# Options with JavaCompiler API

Tags: compiler-construction, javac, java

I have a program like this: it compiles files in memory and then executes them from memory. Therefore I needed a custom classloader with a file manager that stores files in memo://.
Now I want to pass parameters to the compilers outputted class, since I think it does not inherit them (`-Xmx80M`, `-Djava.library.path` etc.). I would think I would need the -J option for this, however the compiler returns an `IllegalArgumentException`. `com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions.getJavacToolOptions(null)` doesn't list **-J** either, so I'm thinking I'm trying to put the argument in the wrong place. Any experience with where I should use -J (or an other option for that matter)?

Edit: `com.sun.tools.javac.main.RecognizedOptions.getAll(null)` reports **-J** as an option, however`getJavacToolOptions(null`) does not, and neither `getJavacFileManagerOptions(null)`.

To clarify, I want to use the LWJGL library with the (runtime)compiled code. LWJGL requires some native libraries from the `-Djava.library.path`, which is set for the project. However the compiled code is not able to find this library path. I'm thinking it does not inherit this library path, and therefor LWJGL throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Else, it might interpret the relative library path wrong as memo://lib/lwjgl, but I have no way to check.

Stack:

```
Aug 22, 2011 2:14:58 PM customcompile.CustomCompile$2 run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at customcompile.CustomCompile$2.run(CustomCompile.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.Sys
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:111)
...
```

I also must note that libraries included by the project are loaded successfully, however the LWJGL library loads additional native libraries - which does not work I think.

Custom classloader:
    package customcompile;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject.Kind;

/**
 *
 * @author Kaj Toet
 */
class MemoryClassLoader extends ClassLoader {


    private JavaCompiler compiler;
    private final MemoryFileManager manager;

    public MemoryClassLoader(JavaCompiler compiler, String classname, String filecontent) {
        this(compiler, Collections.singletonMap(classname, filecontent));
    }

    public MemoryClassLoader(JavaCompiler compiler, Map<String, String> map) {
            this.compiler=compiler;

            DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

            manager  = new MemoryFileManager(this.compiler);
            List<Source> list = new ArrayList<Source>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                list.add(new Source(entry.getKey(), Kind.SOURCE, entry.getValue()));
            }            

            List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
            // set compiler's classpath to be same as the runtime's
            //optionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-cp", ".."));

            this.compiler.getTask(null, this.manager, diagnostics, optionList, null, list).call();
            for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
              CustomCompile.addDebugText(diagnostic.toString());
            }
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        synchronized (this.manager) {
            Output mc = this.manager.map.remove(name);
            if (mc != null) {
                byte[] array = mc.toByteArray();
                return defineClass(name, array, 0, array.length);
            }
        }
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}
```

Custom filemanager:

```
class MemoryFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager> {
    public final Map<String, Output> map = new HashMap<String, Output>();

    MemoryFileManager(JavaCompiler compiler) {
        super(compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null));
    }

    @Override
    public Output getJavaFileForOutput
            (Location location, String name, Kind kind, FileObject source) {
        Output mc = new Output(name, kind);
        this.map.put(name, mc);
        return mc;
    }  
}
```

Output:

```
class Output extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Output(String name, Kind kind) {
        super(URI.create("memo:///" + name.replace('.', '/') + kind.extension), kind);
    }

    byte[] toByteArray() {
        return this.baos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public ByteArrayOutputStream openOutputStream() {
        return this.baos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading the OpenGL libraries from your custom class loader, too? If so, you might try letting them load from your main class loader (and indicating this one as the parent of your main class loader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the compiler API, the compiler will run in the same VM as your main program, sharing its memory with it.

The classes which you are compiling don't have any such settings - these are settings for the Java VM, not for any classes.
If you want to load these classes later in your main program, too, they will also share the memory with your main program.

So, I don't see any sense in using these arguments.

Comment: That's what I thought initially. However -Djava.library.path is set correctly in the projects VM arguments and still the compiled code doesn't load the library from the path. Sorry if my wording isn't correct.

Comment: This should work, too, but isn't really relating to the problem in your original question.

Comment: But unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried the exact same code without running it through a runtime compiler, and then it worked perfectly. I looked quite long and found the -J option here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options

Comment: Sorry, you don't really describe your problem. What are you doing, what are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead? ("Does not work" is no good description.) Add it to the question, not a comment, please.

Comment: I tried my best to clarify it, it was a little late when I wrote this. I described my particular situation somewhat more, so the issue becomes more apparent.

Comment: It does not depend on the compiler, but on the class loading process, if at all. (But NoClassDefFoundError does not seem to indicate a missing library - this would be an UnsatisfiedLinkError. Please post the whole stack trace of your error, as well as the relevant code of your custom class loader).

Comment: However if I run the runtimecompiled code without the JavaCompiler, it runs fine. If I leave out the java.library.path then, it generates the same error as I have when running it runtimecompiled (with JavaCompiler). So this would suggest there is a problem with the library path.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann, The `NoClassDefFoundError` say "Could not initialize class..." (not could not find), there maybe something wrong in a `static{}` block.

Comment: @Kaj: I think the problem is your custom class loader, not the javaCompiler. But as you aren't showing this class loader code (and how it relates to the OpenGL classes), I can only glass-ball-guess here.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know which file (dll) do the class use? If you do, try working around the problem by calling `System.loadLibrary` manually before you do your compile.

Comment: I've looked into this, however LWJGL has OS dependent libraries and thus I would much rather have this handled by LWJGL, also in the future perspective of updates.

Comment: @Kaj Toet, Just call `org.lwjgl.Sys.initialize()` then. It is easier this way.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that comment! The libraries are having difficulty being loaded, because they're 32 bit libraries. I'm using an older LWJGL which does not have 64 bit libraries included.

Comment: @J-16: Could you add this comment to the answer?

Comment: Now I'm getting packages not found in the compiled code, I can perfectly access it in my "original" code. Only thing I can think of I really changed is that I signed all my jars myself.